# Get ID of LI element not working when in function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can grab the ID of the LI element using JQuery's click function, but when I make my own function the ID of the LI element comes up undefined:

http://codepen.io/omarel/pen/gwvpvQ

The first LI element uses Jquery's click function. The second element uses it's own function where the ID comes up undefined.

HTML

```
 <ul id="pricerange_options" class=" options">

    <li id="option1" data-value="1" class="dropdown-option">1</li>

    <li id="option2" data-value="1" class="dropdown-option" onClick="chooseDropDownOption();">2</li>

 </ul>
```

JQuery

```
  function chooseDropDownOption() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    }

  $('#pricerange_options li').click(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
   });
```

Comment: Don't use inlie script... Here issue is that it is run on global context, `this` refers to `window`

Comment: You're just calling a function, which means is `this` value will be the default (`window` or `undefined`). You need to pass an argument, or explicitly set `this` using `.call` or `.apply`.

Comment: ...also, you don't need `.attr()` to get the ID. Just do `this.id` instead.

Comment: Inline handlers are useful if you need immediate availability of the handler functionality. I wouldn't use them in the regular case, but for this and a couple other reasons, they shouldn't be dismissed carelessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you attach an unobtrusive event handler in jQuery the function runs under the scope of the element that raised the event, therefore the `this` keyword refers to the element.

When attaching an event through an `on*` event attribute it runs under the scope of the `window`, hence `this` refers to the `window`. To fix the problem, send the element as a parameter to your function:

```js
function chooseDropDownOption(el) {
  alert($(el).attr('id')); // or just el.id
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pricerange_options" class=" options">
  <li id="option2" data-value="1" class="dropdown-option" onClick="chooseDropDownOption(this);">2</li>
</ul>
```

It should be noted though that using `on*` event handlers is very outdated. You should always use unobtrusive event handlers where possible.